# The cause and solution in unclear ym photo sharing

Tags: internet, chat, irc, yahoo-messenger

Is it because of slow internet connection that the image shared on the other side is unclear and only shows pixels.
Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are interlaced, then it is a distinct possibility. However, more details (such as software) would need to be known. But, we would have to be talking about a really slow connection (like a dial up one - preferably a slow one) for this to be the case.

As well, the image could always simply be low res.